# Calling the URL using urllib2 using insecure flag

Tags: python, python-2.7, request, urllib2

I'm getting an ssl certificate error when trying to pass the header to the url using urllib2 in Python 2.7.10.
Is there an equivalent way for the command curl -k --header 'host:' 'https://' in Python?

Any other alternate solutions is also appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could tried the [Requests package](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/master/).
It's recommended for a higher-level http client interface.